# Decrease latency on camera view

Tags: python

I read Ip camera but 500ms latency occurred on camera view. How can I decrease this value?

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp:admin:admin@192.168.1.108/mpeg4 ")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

       cap.release()
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got that latency and the solution for that can be found here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/

Comment: unfortunately I did not understand what is explained. By the way, giving codes didn't run.